# Why doesn't Eclipse add @Override annotations in "Generate Delegate Methods" refactoring?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, code-generation, eclipse-jdt

In Eclipse, if I try to apply a "Generate Delegate Methods" refactoring to a Java class like the following:

```
class Foo implements Bar {
   Bar bar;
}
```

Eclipse doesn't generate `@Override` annotations for the generated methods.  Is this a bug or is there a good reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No good reason, but not a "bug", *per se*; just a shortcoming. Probably the refactoring is just older than `@Override` -- older than annotations in general, of course -- and has never been updated.

Comment: Thanks Ernest, I reported this to Eclipse's Bugzilla.

Comment: The Bugzilla report can be found [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=346872).

Answer (score 31):

This doesn't answer your question of why it doesn't add the `@Override` annotation when you generate delegate methods, but you can add a save action to do it for you upon saving the file. Go to

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions
```

[image: Eclipse Save Actions]

Notice the entries for `@Override` in the `Additional actions` section. If those are missing for you, click the `Configure...` button and select the `Missing Code` tab and select those options:

[image]

If you want to add the annotations to an entire project or package in
bulk, select the project or package (or multiples), right-click, and
choose Source > Clean up...

In the Clean Up dialog, you can configure a custom profile that includes
adding missing annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes settings in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions cause undesired effects especially on XML files while developing Android applications (been there, experienced that). IMHO better solution is to use +1 or right click on package (or class etc...) and then choose Source -> Clean up to add all of your missing @Override annotations.